# Which XML DTD is Valid

Tags: xml, database, dtd

I have this question in a worksheet, but I've gotten it wrong about 5 times now, can someone please help?

Here is an XML DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE meal [
    <!ELEMENT meal (person*,food*,eats*)>
    <!ELEMENT person EMPTY>
    <!ELEMENT food EMPTY>
    <!ELEMENT eats EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST person name ID #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST food name ID #REQUIRED>
   <!ATTLIST eats diner IDREF #REQUIRED dish IDREF #REQUIRED>
]>
```

Which of the following documents match the DTD?

```
<meal>
    <person name="Alice"/>
    <food name="salad"/>
    <eats diner="Alice" dish="salad"/>
    <person name="Bob"/>
    <food name="salad"/>
    <eats diner="Bob" dish="salad"/>
    <person name="Carol"/>
    <food name="sandwich"/>
    <eats diner="Carol" dish="sandwich"/>
</meal>
```

---

```
<meal>
    <person name="Alice"/>
    <person name="Bob"/>
    <person name="Carol"/>
    <person name="Dave"/>
    <food name="salad"/>
    <food name="turkey"/>
    <food name="sandwich"/>
    <eats diner="Alice" dish="turkey"/>
    <eats diner="Bob" dish="salad"/>
    <eats diner="turkey" dish="Dave"/>
</meal>
```

---

```
<meal>
    <person name="Alice"/>
    <person name="Bob"/>
    <food name="salad"/>
    <eats diner="Alice" dish="food"/>
    <eats diner="Bob" dish="food"/>
</meal>
```

- Only the second
- Only the second and third
- Only the first and third
- Only the first

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Only the second.

The first is invalid because `meal` must contain zero or more `person` followed by zero or more `food` followed by zero or more `eats`.

The third is invalid because there are no ID type attributes with the value `food`. (`dish` is an attribute type `IDREF`)

Answer (score 2):

The first example has two elements with the same value for an id attribute.
`<food name="salad"/>` is repeated so this is not valid. (And as mentioned in the other answer, order is important)

The third example has a value for an idref attribute that is not an id attribute of any element `<eats diner="Bob" dish="food"/>` - "food" is not an id of any element.

The second, although it looks a little strange to us as humans interpreting it with `<eats diner="turkey" dish="Dave"/>` is valid, since those attributes are both idref attributes elsewhere. The dtd doesn't specify that an idref has to be an id attribute that a particular type of element has, even though that's the only way it would make sense to us.

Comment: Good catch on the duplicate ID in the first instance. I was looking at this on my phone and stopped looking for issues once I found the obvious one. +1